# Как изменить код сайта, чтобы его видели другие пользователи?

Tags: php, сервер, веб-сервер

**Приветствую.**

У меня есть вопрос по поводу **взаимодействия пользователей с сайтом**.

Расскажите, пожалуйста, как же всё-таки сделать так, чтобы **все пользователи могли видеть происходящие на сайте изменения**.
Информация каким-то образом должна быть **связана с сервером и серверным языком?** (Например, **PHP**). Если да, то каким образом (если мы говорим в целом, сильной конкретики не нужно, просто принцип).

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: В режиме реального времени чтобы все видели изменения? Или нет? А то я могу перезагрузить страницу а там уже новая инфа, а можно делать realtime обновления

Comment: Необязательно в режиме реального времени, просто, чтобы информация была изменена. После перезагрузки её станет видно всем пользователям, находящихся на сайте. xd

Comment: Но если есть возможность, то объясните, пожалуйста, и реальное время. Если вас не затруднит.